# How many chart types are supported by sparkline highchart?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, sparklines

I'm using **highcharts** in angular to display charts. However, I need to display charts inside a table for which I'm following [this stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-sparkline?file=src%2Fapp%2Fspark-line%2Fspark-line.component.ts).
I can change series.type as 'area', 'column', 'pie' to view line, bar and pie charts. But how many other types of charts are supported here. I referred [highcharts sparkline demo](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sparkline), but they haven't provided enough documentation here.
Please help, if you know any other chart-types supported using highcharts in angular.

Comment: Hi @tushar, You can use all chart types in a table. The only limitation is related to the place you have in a table cell.

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek, for your reply. I got it, we can place any type of chart, but as you said dimension in which we going to fit it can cause bit issues.